# SQL into LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a big problem.

I'm for last 5 year SQL-boy, but now I need to convert my SQL query into LINQ to entity C# format. 
Because I'm new in LINQ (complex statements) right now I need fast help.

Thank's in advance.

P.S. also I need some advices, some start point to start rapidly to learn LINQ to entities.

Here is my SQL (direct from my app(@endDate,@endDate and @glChartID remain as parameters also in my c# app)):

```
SELECT budget.accountid,   
budget.perioddate,
budget.lastyear,
budget.thisyear,   
budget.budget,   
budget.operplan,
budget.forecast,   
glchart.accounttype,
glchart.headertype

FROM budget INNER JOIN glchart ON budget.accountid = glchart.id
WHERE budget.accountid = @glChartID AND budget.perioddate BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate AND glchart.headertype NOT LIKE 'Header%'

UNION

SELECT  glchart.id,   
budget.perioddate,   
SUM(ISNULL(budget.lastyear, 0)),   
SUM(ISNULL(budget.thisyear, 0)),    
SUM(ISNULL(budget.budget, 0)),    
SUM(ISNULL(budget.operplan, 0)),  
SUM(ISNULL(budget.forecast, 0)),  
glchart.accounttype,
glchart.headertype

FROM budget INNER JOIN glchart ON budget.accountid = glchart.id
WHERE budget.accountid  
IN 
(SELECT g.id FROM glchart g
WHERE g.code >= glchart.code AND g.code <  

CASE
WHEN glchart. headerlevel = 1 AND
(SELECT MAX(g3.code)
FROM glchart g3
WHERE g3.headerlevel = 1
) = glchart.code
THEN 
(SELECT MAX(g2.code)
FROM glchart g2
WHERE g2.code >= g.code)
ELSE
(SELECT MIN(g2.code)
FROM glchart g2
WHERE g2.code > glchart.code AND
g2.headerlevel  = glchart. headerlevel) END ) AND
glchart.id = @glChartID AND
budget.perioddate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND
glchart.headertype LIKE 'Header%'

GROUP BY glchart.id, budget.perioddate, glchart.accounttype, glchart.headertype
```

Until today, I managed (thanks to DOK)how to do it and this is how my LINQ is look like right now:

```
var query = ((ObjectQuery<Budget>)(                

                            from budgets in this.ObjectContext.Budgets

                            join glcharts in this.ObjectContext.GLCharts on new { AccountID = budgets.AccountID } equals new { AccountID = glcharts.ID }
                            where
                                    (!(from glC in this.ObjectContext.GLCharts
                                     where Convert.ToInt16(glC.Code) >= Convert.ToInt16(glcharts.Code) && glC.Code != (Convert.ToInt64(glcharts.HeaderLevel) == 1 &&

                                         (from g3 in this.ObjectContext.GLCharts
                                             where  Convert.ToInt64(g3.HeaderLevel) == 1
                                              select new {g3.Code}).Max(p => p.Code) == glcharts.Code ? 
                                                (from g2 in this.ObjectContext.GLCharts
                                                    where Convert.ToInt16(g2.Code) >= Convert.ToInt16(glC.Code)
                                                      select new {g2.Code}).Max(p => p.Code) : 
                                                (from g2 in this.ObjectContext.GLCharts
                                                     where Convert.ToInt16(g2.Code) > Convert.ToInt16(glcharts.Code) && g2.HeaderLevel == glcharts.HeaderLevel
                                                      select new {g2.Code}).Min(p => p.Code))
                                    select new {glC.ID}

                                 ).Contains(new { budgets.AccountID }) &&  

                                 glcharts.ID == 2376 && budgets.PeriodDate >= StartDate && 
                                 budgets.PeriodDate <= EndDate && 
                                 glcharts.HeaderType.StartsWith("Header"))

                                 ).Contains(new { budgets.AccountID }) &&  glcharts.ID == 2376 && budgets.PeriodDate >= StartDate && budgets.PeriodDate <= EndDate && glcharts.HeaderType.StartsWith("Header")

                                   group new {glc = glcharts, b = budgets} 
                                    by new {
                                     glcharts.ID,
                                     budgets.PeriodDate,
                                     glcharts.AccountType,
                                     glcharts.HeaderType
                                    } into g

                            select new {
                              AccountID = (System.Int32?)g.Key.ID,
                              PeriodDate = (System.DateTime?)g.Key.PeriodDate,
                              LastYear = g.Sum(p => ((System.Decimal?)p.t.LastYear ?? (System.Decimal?)0)),
                              ThisYear = g.Sum(p => ((System.Decimal?)p.t.ThisYear ?? (System.Decimal?)0)),
                              Budget = g.Sum(p => ((int?)p.t.Budget1 ?? (int?)0)), 
                              OperPlan = g.Sum(p => ((System.Decimal?)p.t.OperPlan ?? (System.Decimal?)0)),
                              Forecast = g.Sum(p => ((System.Decimal?)p.t.Forecast ?? (System.Decimal?)0)),
                              AccountType = g.Key.AccountType,
                              HeaderType = g.Key.HeaderType
                                        }));

        return query;
```

But in THIS LINE: **.Contains(new { budgets.AccountID })** I'm getting next error :

> Error 8'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Does anybody have an idea where I'm wrong?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 6):

You might find some help in this [excellent reference site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx).

That will lead you to, for example, [two examples for UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#union1).

If you really must start out at this level of difficulty, you might consider breaking your SQL down into pieces and getting them working bit by bit. Do the first `SELECT` without the `JOIN` or `WHERE`, then add those one at a time. Then do the second `SELECT` the same way. Then add the `UNION`.

By the time you get this one worked out, SQL-boy, you will definitely be LINQ-man!

Comment: Hi DOK, thank you for your support. Links you gave to me were very useful so I managed how to rewrite my SQL into LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I am so glad to hear that, Dejan. And thanks for editing your answer to show your result.